# How to write to a specific cell in excel using Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am coding below steps in Python and need to correct code to write a value to specific cell in excel.

1. Read sql from specific cell in excel e.g. B1
2. make db connection and run sql
3. Store/write the Sql output to Result Column. e.g. C1

TestResult excel Sheet:

[image]

Code

```
import pandas
#1
result_df = pandas.read_excel("P:\TestResultSheet.xlsx", "TestResult")
sqlRun = result_df.query("Jira_Num == 'XXXX-01' ")["TestQuery"]
#2 : Got sql output e.g. 110,000
#3 
result_df.loc[sqlRun.index, "ActualResult"] = 110,000
result_df.to_excel("P:\TestResultSheet.xlsx", "TestResult")
```

Above code is not writing to existing column ActualResult and creating another columns with same name and writing result as (also this is deleting other sheets):

```
result_df

     Jira_Num TestQuery                   ActualResult ActualResult
0    XXXX-01     Seelct count (*) from XYZ    NaN         110,000
```

Comment: did the solution below work?

Answer (score 1):

I pulled this from my script and edited in your keywords. This works for me. I use `openpyxl`.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("P:\TestResultSheet.xlsx")
ws = wb["TestResult"]
ws.write('C2', result_df.query("Jira_Num == 'XXXX-01' ")["TestQuery"])
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thanks but Cell coordinate I need to know at run time. like in above example if I am running first query i.e. B2 then i need to enter data in C2. 
i might not executing query in sequence.  
result_df.loc[sqlRun.index, "ActualResult"] = 110,000  >> this code is workin to identify the cell .

So I am just facing issue with writing back the result in existing sheet without removing other sheet.

Comment: If you update the question with the specific problem I might be able to help. Sounds like you might need to use `ws.cell(row=2, column=2).value = result_df.query("Jira_Num == 'XXXX-01' ")["TestQuery"]` or something similar instead of referencing cells by the Alpha-Numeric way. (you could probably use a loop to get exactly what you need).

Comment: Ok, This is what i am trying to achieve.
I have an excel with columns: Jira ID, TestQuery and TestResult........ This code give me the query to run for given Jira id....... result_df.query("Jira_Num == 'XXXX-01' ")["TestQuery"] .......Output of Query is '110000' ......Now at run time I need to write back the result in TestResult Column Without affecting other sheets in Workbook.

Comment: Result_df = pandas.read_excel("P:\TestResultSheet.xlsx", "TestResult")


    sqlRun = result_df.query("Jira_Num == 'XXXX-01' ")["TestQuery"]


    result_df.loc[sqlRun.index, "ActualResult"] = 110000


    result_df1 = result_df.set_index('Test_Id')

 
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('P:\TestResultSheet.xlsx',engine ='xlsxwriter')


    writer.save()

this code work fine but it remove all other worksheets.

Comment: Can you edit the question and write your new comments in there instead?

Answer (score 0):

@ jpf5046 thanks for all help. 
I tried below code after taking reference from other similar issue found on stackoverflow and worked fine. Below code write to specific sheet without removing the existing sheets and formatting in same workbook.

code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


result_df.loc[sqlRun.index, "ActualResult"] = 110,000
result_df1 = result_df.set_index('Test_Id')
workBook = load_workbook('P:\TestResultSheet.xlsx')
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('P:\TestResultSheet.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = workBook
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in workBook.worksheets)
result_df1.to_excel(writer, 'TestResult')
writer.save()
```